# List related wiki-pages (Sharepoint-Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template, wiki, wiki-pages

A SharePoint page should be among other things used by our developers to store developer documentation. I don't really know much about SharePoint sites yet, but I thought that wiki sites are the best way to do that. These are to be stored in a separate area. Related pages should be listed on the page.

My Question is: **How can I implement the (automatic) listing of related pages on wiki-pages?**

Comment: Thanks for editing. There are now two questions, so it's a step closer!

Comment: @TomResing So now I finally made it, I guess. Now it should comply with the guidelines.

Comment: Getting down to one question is an important guideline of this community. I've voted to re-open. In the meantime, I recommend checking out the following article. In step 7, the author makes a number of suggestions for dynamic linking to SharePoint pages which can be used like wikis. https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-build-an-awesome-knowledge-base-wiki-in-sharepoint-online-using-modern-pages/